# How to sample non-uniformly from a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, random

Could you please advise how to sample from a distribution with defined probabilities (or better solution of my problem below):

I have a list of items. I can currently sample from it with `rand_word = randint(0, total_num)`. But I would like elements later in the list to appear more often.

For example, I would like the items from the first 20% of the list to appear with probability 10% and the last 20% to appear with 50 to 60% probability, as an example. (Though perhaps the distribution could be more complex.)

Comment: This question is currently about statistics, not programming.

Comment: This sounds like a two-step process. First, define the weights for each element of the list. Second, sample using something like [random.choices](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) or [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). The former accepts a list of weights (unnormalized probabilities) for each item; the latter accepts a list of (normalized) probabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is extremely open-ended, so there are an infinite number of distributions that could meet your requirement as stated.  Depending on which distribution you actually want, the implementations could vary widely.

That said, a correctly parameterized [triangle distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) will sample less frequently from the beginning of a list, and more frequently from the end.  Here's a straightforward implementation:

```
from random import random
from math import sqrt

def sample_triangle(ary):
    return ary[int(len(ary) * sqrt(random()))]
```

Taking the square root of a continuous Uniform(0,1) generates a continuous triangular random variable with the min equal 0, and the max and mode both equal to 1.  Multiplying it by the length of a list and integerizing it will turn it into a valid list index that has an integer triangle distribution.

Here's the result of a sample run with 10,000 values generated from a list containing the numbers 1 to 20:

[image: Histogram of generated triangle distribution.]